# Firebase database is getting structured incorrectly

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing a Flutter app with Firebase Database. This is a chat app. The database structure I need is as the following.

[image]

So, I first create a `chat room` and then add its `members`. Here please consider the key `900` as a key in `chat_room` (i know its not in this example), acting as the foreign key in `members` node. According to the current structure, I can add any number of `members` to a `chat room` and I can easily find them without downloading lot of data. This is achievable by the following code.

**fire_database_service.dart**

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';

class FireDatabaseService
{

  final DatabaseReference _chatRoomReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('chat_room');

  //Create chat_room
  Future<String> createChatRoom({String lastMessage, String chatMode}) async {
    
    var newChatRoomRef = _chatRoomReference.push();
    var newChatRoomKey = newChatRoomRef.key;
    await newChatRoomRef.set({
      'last_message': lastMessage,
      'chat_mode': chatMode,
      'timestamp': DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch,
      
    });

    return newChatRoomKey;
  }

  Future<void> addChatMembers(List<ChatMember> chatMembers, String chatRoomID) async
  {
    for(int i=0; i<chatMembers.length; i++)
    {
      ChatMember chatMemeber = chatMembers[i];

      var newChatMemberReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('members/$chatRoomID/').push();
      var newChatMemberKey = newChatMemberReference.key;
     await newChatMemberReference.set({
      'email': chatMemeber.email,
      'userID': chatMemeber.userID,
      'user_role': chatMemeber.userRole,
      
    });
    }
    return null;
  }

}
```

**chat.dart**

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();

    FireDatabaseService firebaseDatabase = FireDatabaseService();
    String chatRoomID="";

    firebaseDatabase.createChatRoom(
    lastMessage: "Test",
    chatMode: "Supplier").then((value)  async{
      print("CHAT ID: "+value);


      ChatMember member1 = new ChatMember(
      email: "someone@test.com",
      userRole: "customer",
      userID: 30
    );

    ChatMember member2 = new ChatMember(
      email: "anotherone@test.com",
      userRole: "supplier",
      userID: 50
    );

    List<ChatMember> chatMemberList = [member1, member2];

    print("BEFORE");
    await firebaseDatabase.addChatMembers(chatMemberList, "900");
    print("AFTER");
    });

    
  }
```

Please note that in this line `await firebaseDatabase.addChatMembers(chatMemberList, "900");` I am hardcoding the value `900`. Instead of this, if I pass the unique key of the `chat room` node, I get this structure, which is completely incorrect of what i need.

[image]

I actually need this unique key of `chat room` to be in `members` node, so it will act as the `foreign key` in `members` node.

Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue. It was because the `chatRoomID` is not getting the unique key, it was empty. I fixed it in the following way.

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();

    FireDatabaseService firebaseDatabase = FireDatabaseService();

    firebaseDatabase
        .createChatRoom(lastMessage: "Test", chatMode: "Supplier")
        .then((value) async {
      print("CHAT ID: " + value);

      ChatMember member1 = new ChatMember(
          email: "someone@test.com",
          userRole: "customer",
          userID: 30,
          profilePic: "");

      ChatMember member2 = new ChatMember(
          email: "anotherone@test.com", userRole: "supplier", userID: 50);

      List<ChatMember> chatMemberList = [member1, member2];

      print("BEFORE");
      await firebaseDatabase.addChatMembers(chatMemberList, value);
      print("AFTER");
    });
  }
```